# Can't deploy Flask with Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am trying to follow this guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to run flask app with ngnix. I followed everything but nginx still serves the default page and not from my app.

Attached are my conf files -

`app.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi
callable = app

master = true
processes = 3

socket = potter.sock
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Upstart script `potter.conf`

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve potter"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid root
setgid root

env PATH=/root/jobs_env/bin
chdir /root/potter
exec uwsgi --ini app.ini
```

`nginx.conf`

```
user root;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

`potter` in `sites-enabled` for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 178.62.31.95;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/root/potter/potter.sock;
    }
}
```

EDIT -

I get the following error in nginx error logs -

```
2015/05/06 16:46:12 [error] 19614#0: *3 connect() to unix:/tmp/potter.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.193.186.206, server: potter.hack, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/potter.sock:", host: "178.62.31.95"
```

Comment: Have you defined an upstream socket (I mean, <ip>:<port>) in potter.sock? If your acces.log and error.log files don't show you what is failing, you can create a different log file adding the `logto` parameter to the .ini file. Also, probably harcoding the socket in the .ini file would solve the problem

Comment: @SebasSBM sorry, but how you will to define ip:port in `unix sockets` ?)

Comment: I would do the way I used to for Django -see answer below. I guess it is the right way to go.

Comment: Error logs from nginx ? I'd guess the default site overrides the one you are trying to setup

Comment: Tasos Vogiatzoglou is probably right. @Siddharth make sure that default site is not enabled (just remove the symlink from sites-enabled)

Comment: I have removed the default site altogether!

Comment: The nginx error points to the unix socket at `/tmp/potter.sock`. Your app.ini file specifies the socket just as `potter.sock`, so the socket will go to the current directory, which appears to `/root/potter`. Can that be the problem?

Comment: @Miguel yeah I noticed that and fixed that, still the same problem remains.

Comment: Please update the config files and log output after the fix. Also check your file system to verify that the potter.sock file exists in the expected place.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with these changes:

`app.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
...
socket = 127.0.0.1:5678 # Use the inner port you want for this
...
```

in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/potter` add:

```
upstream uwsgi_myupsocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:5678;
}

server {

    [...]

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi_myupsocket;
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

I hope this will help.

EDIT: You can try to execute manually the .ini file from shell:

> root@yourmachine:~/potter# uwsgi app.ini

Output should give information about what's wrong with the configuration

Comment: By the way, wouldn't it be better to put potter in sites-available and symlink it to sites-enabled?

Comment: This doesnt change anything for me. I still see the nginx welcome screen. Any other things I could try? Or any other information that might be useful for debugging this?

Comment: You can add a third log file in `app.ini` like this: `logto = /somepath/uwsgi.log` (maybe you will have to create the LOG file manually). It helped me to spot the errors in a similar situation.

Comment: I added the log file for `app.ini`. It gets created automatically. When making a request to the server from the browser, nothing comes on the nginx error or access logs and nothing on the log file for `app.ini`. The nginx welcome page is still served.

Comment: I tried running the `uwsgi app.ini` file - it does not give me any error. After more tinkering, I now get a 502 gateway error. And I get an error in nginx error log - `"2015/05/06 16:46:12 [error] 19614#0: *3 connect() to unix:/tmp/potter.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 113.193.186.206, server: potter.hack, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/potter.sock:", host: "178.62.31.95""`